# How to turn a pre-made list in rows and columns just like a matrix into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np



url = "https://www.bls.gov/web/ximpim/beaimp.htm"

page = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

table1 = doc.find('table', id='main-content-table')

data_points = doc.find_all("span",{"class":"datavalue"})
numbers = [x.text for x in data_points]
numbers1 = numbers[651:1107]
numbers2 = numbers[2431:2900]
df1 = np.matrix(numbers1)

df2 = np.matrix(numbers2)





headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text
    headers.append(title)
table1 = headers[72:111]
table2 = headers[225:265]


datafile = pd.DataFrame([table1,numbers1])
datafile = datafile.transpose()
datafile.columns=['Category','0']
datafile.head()

datafile.to_csv('hello.csv', header=False)
```

The idea is to have it into a csv file:
Columns are suppose to included the title and then follow by a 0 for each columns
I thought I could convert it into a 38 by 12 matrix
The output I want is:

```
All imports excluding petroleum 
1985    0   0    0     0    0    0      0   0    0      0   0    0

    -   -   73.9    -   -   74.3    -   -   74.8    -   -   76.8
```

1986

```
    -   -   79.1    -   -   79.9    -   -   82.5    -   -   82.9
```

1987

```
    -   -   84.8    -   -   87.0    -   -   87.7    -   -   90.2
```

1988

```
    -   -   92.3    -   -   94.6    -   -   94.0    -   -   96.2
```

1989

```
    96.9    96.1    96.7    96.4    96.7    95.9    95.2    95.1    95.2    95.5    95.7    96.0
```

1990

```
    96.1    96.4    96.9    96.7    96.4    96.4    96.3    96.8    97.6    98.0    98.3    98.9
```

1991

```
    99.0    99.3    99.6    98.9    98.8    98.3    97.8    97.8    98.0    98.5    98.7    99.1
```

1992

```
    99.8    100.0   99.8    99.1    99.0    99.5    99.9    100.3   100.7   101.2   100.9   99.9
```

1993

```
    99.9    99.7    99.9    100.2   100.6   100.5   100.7   100.8   100.9   101.4   101.3   101.3
```

1994

```
    101.6   101.5   101.8   102.1   102.3   102.6   103.1   103.8   104.1   104.8   105.1   105.2
```

1995

```
    105.5   105.9   106.4   107.0   107.7   107.6   108.0   108.0   107.8   107.5   107.7   107.7
```

1996

```
    107.4   107.4   107.1   107.0   106.7   106.2   105.9   105.7   106.1   105.8   105.7   105.8
```

1997

```
    105.4   105.3   104.9   104.3   104.2   104.3   104.1   103.8   103.7   103.4   103.3   102.8
```

1998

```
    102.2   101.7   101.4   101.1   100.9   100.5   100.0   99.6    99.4    99.5    99.6    99.4
```

1999

```
    99.5    99.4    99.0    98.8    99.0    98.8    98.6    98.7    98.9    99.0    99.4    99.4
```

2000

```
    99.4    99.7    100.0   100.1   99.9    99.9    100.2   100.3   100.0   100.0   99.9    100.7
```

2001

```
    101.6   100.8   100.0   99.5    99.2    98.9    97.8    97.5    97.3    96.8    96.6    96.2
```

2002

```
    96.1    95.7    95.8    96.3    96.2    96.2    96.2    96.3    96.4    96.4    96.3    96.5
```

2003

```
    96.8    97.1    98.1    97.1    96.9    97.3    97.3    97.0    97.3    97.2    97.4    97.7
```

2004

```
    98.5    98.9    99.1    99.4    99.6    99.7    99.7    100.0   100.1   100.0   100.9   101.3
```

2005

```
    101.6   101.7   102.0   102.4   102.2   102.0   101.8   101.9   102.8   103.8   103.7   103.7
```

2006

```
    104.0   103.3   103.0   103.1   103.8   104.2   104.2   104.7   104.8   104.2   105.2   105.7
```

2007

```
    105.6   105.6   105.9   106.2   106.8   107.1   107.2   107.2   107.1   107.7   108.5   108.9
```

2008

```
    109.7   110.4   111.6   113.1   113.9   114.9   115.6   115.1   114.0   113.0   111.1   109.9
```

2009

```
    109.0   108.2   107.3   107.1   107.3   107.4   107.2   107.6   107.9   108.4   109.1   109.7
```

2010

```
    110.3   110.4   110.3   110.8   111.2   110.7   110.5   110.7   111.0   111.3   112.2   112.6
```

2011

```
    113.6   114.4   115.0   115.9   116.4   116.4   116.5   116.8   117.0   116.6   116.3   116.4
```

2012

```
    116.4   116.3   116.7   116.7   116.6   116.3   115.9   115.8   116.0   116.4   116.4   116.5
```

2013

```
    116.6   116.6   116.5   116.5   116.1   115.7   115.0   114.8   114.8   114.9   115.0   115.2
```

2014

```
    115.7   116.0   116.5   116.1   116.0   115.8   115.8   115.7   115.6   115.4   115.1   115.1
```

2015

```
    114.3   114.0   113.5   113.0   112.9   112.8   112.5   112.1   111.9   111.5   111.2   110.8
```

2016

```
    110.7   110.5   110.4   110.4   110.8   110.5   111.0   111.1   111.2   111.1   111.1   111.1
```

2017

```
    111.2   111.5   111.6   111.9   111.9   112.0   111.9   112.1   112.5   112.5   112.7   112.6
```

2018

```
    113.3   113.7   113.7   113.8   113.9   113.5   113.4   113.1   113.2   113.4   113.5   113.7
```

2019

```
    113.0   113.2   113.2   112.7   112.4   112.0   111.9   111.8   111.8   111.7   111.8   112.0
```

2020

```
    112.1   112.3   112.1   111.5   111.6   111.9   112.1   113.0   113.7   113.6   113.6   114.1
```

2021

```
    115.1   115.7   116.7   117.6   118.8   119.6   119.7   119.7   119.9   120.7   121.5   122.0
```

2022

```
    123.8   124.8   126.2   126.8   126.7   126.0   125.2   124.9   124.5   124.3   123.9   124.9
```

Comment: Since a csv is a simple text, with uniform rows and columns, there are multiple ways of doing this 1) plain python text formatting, 2) with the help of the python `csv` module, 3) from an array with `np.savetxt`, 4) from a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The BLS has a [data API](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_signature_v2.htm) that would be preferable over web scraping. The Series ID is a bit hard to find. It's not what's shown on the page (typical government issue). You can use the [BLS Data Finder](https://beta.bls.gov/dataQuery/find) to get that:

```py
# You can only query 10 years at a time without registering for an API key
step = 10

data = []
for start_year in range(1985, 2023, step):
    payload = {
        # All imports excluding petroleum
        "seriesid": ["EIUIREXPET"],
        "startyear": start_year,
        "endyear": start_year + step - 1
    }
    r = requests.post("https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/", json=payload)
    r.raise_for_status()

    data.extend(r.json()["Results"]["series"][0]["data"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)[["year","period","value"]]
df["period"] = df["period"].str.strip("M").astype(int)
df = df.pivot(index="year", columns="period")
```